# Bluetooth integration with Unity 2D for Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I am writing a game over Unity which requires pairing of a bluetooth keyboard. 
I need it to pair both with iOS and Android.

Do I need to write my own driver, or is there a third party driver which can handle both?

Comment: On iOS the user must pair the keyboard through the settings application. An app cannot initiate pairing with a keyboard

Comment: Pairing would usually be managed on the phone itself. You may see that a keyboard is or isn't present. What else are you hoping to do?

Comment: I need to pair a customized bluetooth keyboard (with 10 buttons), but I could not find any reference how to control it within Unity. Is this possible at all?